# SecretKeyFactory.getInstance() throws exception for all algorithms in unit tests

Tags: java, security, powermock

By some reason I always get exception in unit test when calling SecretKeyFactory.getInstance() no matter what algorithm is specified. For example:

```
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES")

com.mhe.connect.util.EncryptionException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWITHMD5ANDDES SecretKeyFactory not available
```

At the same time, I see that Security.getProviders() returns me needed algorithms:

```
SECRETKEYFACTORY.DESEDE SunJCE
SECRETKEYFACTORY.PBEWITHMD5ANDDES SunJCE
SECRETKEYFACTORY.DES SunJCE
SECRETKEYFACTORY.PBEWITHMD5ANDTRIPLEDES SunJCE
SECRETKEYFACTORY.PBKDF2WITHHMACSHA1 SunJCE
SECRETKEYFACTORY.PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE SunJCE
SECRETKEYFACTORY.PBEWITHSHA1ANDRC2_40 SunJCE
```

This happens only in unit tests (from Maven, or IDE) and works fine if code is running under Jetty (that is run from same Maven/JDK).

What could be the reason for such behavior?

Comment: I found the problem - my unit test was using PowerMockito and it looks that it brakes classpath, or something. Anyway, after removing it and rewriting test a bit, all works fine.

Comment: Unbelievable, I'm glad I'm not the only one who's noticed this.  Evidently the PowerMock guys are aware of this, and it also applies if you're using the BouncyCastle crypto APIs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/3U_ih01cmBA

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ran into the same issue today. Solved it by adding `@PowerMockIgnore ("javax.crypto.*")` to the class.

Does anyone know if I can globally ignore this package? I don't want to add it to every class that executes code from that package.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @T3rm1 that solved my problem!

turns out that running

```
SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(<algorithm>)
```

in a test environment with powermockito the javax.crypto.* must be mocked, and thus throwing **java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException** in my case

```
javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory no such algorithm PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
```