# EncryptionInitializationException using PowerMockRunner and not with MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

When I test below function using MockitoJunitRunner it works fine as expected. But when I am running the same test using PowerMockRunner I get following exception:

> org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException:
>
> ```
> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available
> ```

```
 functionToBeTested() {
         Encryptor.encrypt(this.getIgvToken(), "IGVKEY123");  
    }
```

I am wondering why it throws exception when I use PowerMockRunner. Here are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: PowerMockRunner uses its own classloader so it can rewrite the bytecode of the class-under-test. My hunch is that, by using the different classloader, you interfere with the loading of SecretKeyFactory. I just don't know enough about PowerMock or its classloader hierarchy to be sure of that.

Comment: Adding annotation **@PrepareForTest({Encryptor.class})** worked. I just added ClassUnderTest.class; as a result it was failing. Also needed to add Encryptor.class.

Comment: Glad to hear! Consider adding that as an answer to your own question, then accept it to mark your question as resolved. Other readers may even vote for it later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than class under test also add annotation `@PrepareForTest({Encryptor.class})`.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the exact problem but unfortunately this solution couldn't help me. It got resolved by adding `@PowerMockIgnore ("javax.crypto.*")` in my class as given in the following link:

[SecretKeyFactory.getInstance() throws exception for all algorithms in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805236/secretkeyfactory-getinstance-throws-exception-for-all-algorithms-in-unit-tests)