# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 SecretKeyFactory not available

Tags: java, exception

This is a really odd error. On two machines, the code is running perfectly. I just set this up on a brand new machine and this isn't working. I'm getting the following error when running the script;

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 SecretKeyFactory not available
```

The line of code that is causing the error is;

```
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512" );
```

Using JDK 1.7.0

The code is all compiling correctly, it is just failing at run time on this line. I have a feeling this is some how related to a JAR file that is different or a JDK that is slightly different, but after checking everything across the different machines, everything looks identical.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 was added in Java 8, it is not available in Java 7 by default (Java 7 itself only supports PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1).

Compare:

- [`SecretKeyFactory` Algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) for Java 7

  > `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` Constructs secret keys using the Password-Based Key Derivation Function function found in PKCS #5 v2.0.
- [`SecretKeyFactory` Algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory) for Java 8

  > `PBKDF2With<prf>` Password-based key-derivation algorithm found in PKCS #5 2.0 using the specified pseudo-random function (`<prf>`). Example: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256.

So you need to either upgrade to Java 8, or downgrade to PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1, or check if there is a JCE provider that provides PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 for Java 7 (for example, Bouncy Castle).

If your code is running ok on another machine with Java 7, then check if `lib/ext` of that Java install contains additional libraries, for example Bouncy Castle has a JCE provider that supports PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512. In that case, you will need to include that same library in the Java install of the other machine.

Comment: Looks like an upgrade to Java 8 is going to happen sooner rather than later then. It's pointless debugging this between machines when this definitely works in Java 8. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error because I was running a unit test with `PowerMockRunner`, i.e.:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    //...
}
```

Removing `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` solved the issue for me.

Comment: It's not necessary to remove PowerMock, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249508/7775112

Answer (score 2):

If any **Android developer** came here with the same issue, continue reading.

I was having the same problem.

> NoSuchAlgorithmException: SecretKeyFactory PBKDF2withHmacSHA256
> implementation not found

I tried to upgrade from Java 7 to Java 8 but it didn't helped. Strange was that it was working on some devices and failing on the others. You'll think that `SecretKeyFactory` is in `javax` so it's JDK part and has nothing to do with Android API level.

Thing is that on Android system there are various security providers for different API levels and `SecretKeyFactory` provides implementations of algorithms from that providers, and based on the information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory) `PBKDF2withHmacSHA512` is available from API 26 only. If you want to have functionality working on older Android systems you can switch to  `PBKDF2withHmacSHA1` which is available from API 10 or do/use some custom implementations of desired ones.

**Other option is** copy pasting algorithm's code from `https://gist.github.com/jtan189/3804290` and put in your project.